# Enable portuguese language in babel in a gentoo linux system

Tags: babel, linux

How can a language be enabled in babel on a gentoo linux system? texlive has been installed using the system package management software.

Comment: It would help if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Usually you just need to supply the language name as an option to `babel` e.g. `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`.

Comment: If you need to install, `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese` or try first the package `babel` as cited above.

Comment: @Sigur Gentoo doesn't use `apt`, does it? It would be helpful if Romildo would include details of exactly which commands *were* used to install TeX Live. `emerge` something, I assume, but `emerge` what?

Comment: @cfr, he said that he installed using *system package management* so I guess that he can install that package also there.

Comment: @Sigur Are you sure that's right for Gentoo? The current ebuild for texlive-2013 seems to be http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/app-text/texlive/texlive-2013.ebuild?revision=1.3&view=markup which suggests that inclusion of Portuguese might be managed using use flags rather than via installation of a distinct package. But I don't understand Gentoo's system well enough to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed texlive using the `emerge` command, which is the default package manager for gentoo linux. Features of a package are selected for installation according to the so called `USE` variable.

For the `app-text/texlive-2013` package there are several USE options, including `linguas_pt`, which is the relevant one for this issue. When it is set, it triggers the installation of the dependency package `dev-texlive/texlive-langportuguese`. But somehow the system was not configured  after the installation, in a way that the file `language.dat` file was not updated correctly in order to reflect the installation of the support for the Portuguese language. Because of that my document failed compilation.

Simply reinstalling texlive fixed the issue.